# get String length in StringWriter?

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using `JAXB`, I need to know the length of generated XML, so I marshal the content to `StringWriter`, so which way is better to get the length:

```
aStringWriter.getBuffer().length();
```

```
 or
```

```
aStringWriter.toString().length();
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Calling `toString()` will always create a new string... although it won't need to copy the actual character data, just create a new string referring to the current `char[]` with the current length and count. Calling `getBuffer().length()` doesn't need to create *any* extra objects though, so it's slightly more efficient.

What are you doing with the output though? Aren't you converting it to a string anyway?

Note that the length here will always be the length in *characters* though, so it won't be suitable for something like the Content-Length header of an HTTP responses, which needs the value in *bytes* (i.e. after encoding).

EDIT: Okay, if you want the byte count instead, I suggest you create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and either pass that directly to JAXB if you can (I've forgotten what the API looks like) or create an `OutputStreamWriter` around it. That way you can get the *binary* length from the `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead.

Comment: I'm adding the content to HTTP body, and yes actually, I need to set the Content-Length Header

Comment: @JonSkeet A very good response! `ByteArrayOutputStream` will work perfect for this as you can utilize the JAXB `Marshaller` to marshall into this output-stream, which can subsequently be converted to a `byte[]`. The solution utilizing a `Charset` and a the `String.getBytes()` method works well for a String only. A JAXB `Marshaller` by default uses **UTF-8** encoding, so the resulting marshalled `byte[]` will give you the correct length.  If you wish to use some other type of encoding, then simply call `Marshaller.setProperty()` using the property element `jaxb.encoding`.

Answer (score 1):

I do this

```
Charset UTF8Charset = Charset.forName("UTF8");
String output = stringWriter.toString();
response.setContentType("application/xml");
response.setContentLength(output.getBytes(UTF8Charset).length);
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print(output);
```

Works perfect for all UTF-8 strings.